# Java - Variable name already defined in method

Tags: java, variables

I'm trying to finish this debugging assignment for my intro to Java class and I believe I got most of it right as I am down to one error, here's the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DebugThree3
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String name;
      name = getName(name);
      displayGreeting(name);           
   }
   public static String getName(String name)
   {
      String name;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter name ");
      name = input.nextLine();
      return name;
   }
   public static void displayGreeting(String name)
   {
      System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "!");
   }
}
```

The error says: error: variable name is already defined in method getName(String)
String name;
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Why does your `getName` method declare a parameter?

Comment: Don't name the variable `name` `name` (or don't name the `name` parameter `name`) instead name it something else so `name` isn't already defined. Name name not-name. Tangentially, passing `name` into `getName` is non-sensical.

Comment: Yeah, naming `name` name is not a good name for a function that gets a name. Instead of `name`, name the `name` variable after what the `name` is the name of.  If `name` is the name of a human, called `name` `humanName` or another name of you're choosing :) (had to jump on the fun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String getName(String name)
```

This line defines a method called `getName` with a parameter called `name`.

Received parameters are effectively local variables (i.e. you address them the same way and they use the same namespace).

Then this line

```
String name;
```

tries to define a local variable with the same name. That's not allowed. There would be no way to distinguish the two.

It seems that there's actually no point in accepting the `name` parameter, since you seem to try to just return what the user input, so just change the method definition to look like this:

```
public static String getName()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the 'name' variable in the function `getName`, but it is also passed in as a parameter too, which is what's causing the error.

I *think* from your code, you want to remove the parameter (swap `public static String getName(String name)` to `public static String getName()`) and have the user input the name instead.

You therefore also don't need to define it in `main()`.
I therefore think your code should look like this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DebugThree3
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String name = getName();
      displayGreeting(name);           
   }
   public static String getName()
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter name ");
      return input.nextLine();
   }
   public static void displayGreeting(String name)
   {
      System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "!");
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't even need to declare the local variable `name` at all. You can just return `input.nextLine`

Comment: Good point @QBrute, updated!

Comment: This code won't compile. The variable `name` in `main` is undeclared.

Comment: Should really note that I haven't tried to compile this in my answer, updated the answer, thanks @DavidConrad!